# Minimize Rayleigh quotient in $W^{1,2}_0(U)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $U$ is a bounded, connected open set with $C^\infty$ bondary. Define 
$$\mathcal R(u) = \frac{\int_U |\nabla u|^2}{\int_U u^2}$$
and let $W_0^{1,2}(U)$ be the closure of $C_c^\infty(U)$ in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(U)$. What we want to prove is that there exists $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(U)$ such that $\mathcal R(\phi) = \min_{u\in W_0^{1,2}(U) \\ u\neq 0}\mathcal R(u)$.

My solution is to take $\{u_i\} \subset W_0^{1,2}(U)$ such that $\mathcal R(u_i) \to \mu := \min_{u\in W_0^{1,2}(U)\\ u \neq 0} \mathcal R(u)$. Then define $\phi_i = u_i / \lVert u_i \lVert_{L^2}$.

Since $\phi_i$ and $\nabla \phi_i$ is $L^2(U)$ bounded, We can take subsequence $\{\phi_i\}$ such that $\phi_i$ converges to some $\phi\in L^2(U)$ weakly, and $\nabla \phi_i$ converges to $\nabla \phi$ weakly. Moreover, $\phi_i$ is $W_0^{1,2}(U)$ bounded, then taking subseqence to make sure $\phi_i$ converges in $L^2(U)$.

Now we have $\phi \in W^{1,2}(U)$, but I have no ideas about how to show that $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(U)$. Can anyone give some hints to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have shown that $\phi_i\rightharpoonup \phi$ and $\nabla \phi_i\rightharpoonup \nabla \phi$ weakly in $L^2(U)$,  then
this means that $\phi_i\rightharpoonup \phi$ weakly in $W^{1,2}(U)$. Moreover, $W_0^{1,2}(U)$ is weakly closed in $W^{1,2}(U)$, because it is a closed subspace. Therefore, since $\phi_i\in W_0^{1,2}(U)$ for all $i$, you obtain $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(U)$.

Comment: Thanks! But I am not familiar with the result "$W^{1,2}_0$ is a closed subspace", is there some material about it?

Comment: @miskcoo $W_0^{1,2}$ is a Banach space strictly contained in the Banach space $W^{1,2}$, hence closed, hence weakly closed

Comment: @miskcoo My definition of $W_0^{1,2}$ goes like "the closure of $C_c^{\infty}$ in $W^{1,2}$". Hence, it is  closed by definition. The fact that it is a vector space is also rather straightforward under this definition.